# Backend increment counter PHP or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, counter, backend

After researching I am not really sure which is a matching solution for my project. I want a serverside number incr. counter, that daily resets.
Every website vistor should see the same number of the counter. Is there
a PHP script or javascript meaningful? Can I store the daily counts in a txt.-file without using a database like MySql?

Comment: You can create a txt and save the values there. Then create a crontab to delete the file and create it again. Mysql is the best solution for you

Comment: Yes. It can be done very easily.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you specified a little further what you are trying to achieve. What is the counter counting? number of visits? number of clicks?

You could store this in a text file. I wouldn'r recommend it thought, it will be bulky and you will run into trouble when several updates takes place simultaneously. A better solution if you want an easy and file-based database, check [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/).

Comment: Okay it is not the primary goal to store the counts. More important is just to run an increment number (random number) serverside, that all visitors see the same increment number in a live counter in the frontend.

Comment: The fundamental method to achieve these sync from server - and live client count is not clear to me. The count is just a static method on the backend with no event thats triggers the counts.

Comment: live sync e.g. every 10 or 5 sec

Comment: Alright, well then maybe use javascript to send an ajax request every 10:th second and return the count from your backend? Where do you get in trouble?

Comment: Hey Isak, thats a great idea, do you think the server php increment is done with a cronjob or what u think ?

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable.